# dynamic dependent select box.. set to certain value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on this script which i found here: https://www.webslesson.info/2020/04/dynamic-dependent-select-box-with-search-option-in-php-using-jquery-ajax.html
and it works OK. I want to have though a certain value set for the category item.. Normally you would set this with option value.. which I see is part of the script.. So for example.. in the DB, it is stored that we have cities and countries. So that once I select the category Country -> England, then automatically it will list all of the cities (incl. london) as the subcategory. If then later on you want to modify a user record which is connected to England - London.. by bringing up this script, you would have to select the country and city again.. But I would like it to state England -> London, whereas then i can select, Brighton instead of London.

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Category</label>
            <select name="category_item" id="category_item" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true" title="Select Category"></select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Sub Category</label>
            <select name="sub_category_item" id="sub_category_item" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true" title="Select Sub Category"></select>
          </div>
          
          <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#category_item').selectpicker();

  $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker();

  load_data('category_data');

  function load_data(type, category_id = '')
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"load_data.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{type:type, category_id:category_id},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        var html = '';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
        {
          html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';
        }
        if(type == 'category_data')
        {
          $('#category_item').html(html);
          $('#category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        else
        {
          $('#sub_category_item').html(html);
          $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
      }
    })
  }

  $(document).on('change', '#category_item', function(){
    var category_id = $('#category_item').val();
    load_data('sub_category_data', category_id);
  });
  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need the id or the value of the option tag. Which in your case is *data[count].id*. So to set the value you would use:

```
$('#selector_id').value = data[count].id; // Id or the value of the option you want to set
```

**EDIT:**

In your particular case this will work like this:

```
$('#container_id').value = country_id; //2 for example for England
$('#sub_container_id').value = city_id; //21 for example
```

Comment: Ok.if the country_id would be: 2 and the city_id = 21.. it would be someting like: $('#selector_id').value = 2;.. and the city would then automatically appear too for the id: 21 ?

Comment: Simply replace *data[count].id* with 2 and 21 respectively

Comment: like this: $('#country_selector_id').value = 2; // *change country_selector_id* with the corresponding id in your html

Comment: You have two different selectors, right? One for country and one for city. Is that correct?

Comment: No...only line in the code is: html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';

Comment: So if I replace data[count].id with 21 (for country), it will not pickup the city. BTW. both country and city are read in the userDB and available to the script. ... I also tried $('#container_id').value = country_id; //2 for example for England
$('#sub_container_id').value = city_id; //21 for example, but don't know where to put this code into  th script... and while trying to understand it... where does #container_id and #sub-container_id refer to in the html part?

Comment: These ids are from the **select** tag in your HTML code. You can use the code where you need it within the *document.ready* function from jquery.

Comment: Ok so then it would be: :$('#category_item').value = country_id; //2 for example for England
$('#sub_category_item').value = city_id; //21 for example.. Correct?